# C# How to prevent the event handler assigned to multiple controls being called twice?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm very new to C# and I was having trouble with the event handler in my Windows Forms application. I have multiple radio buttons created during runtime (stored in the `buttonz` list), and all have the same event handler assigned to them.

In a `foreach` loop:

```
buttonz.Add(new RadioButton());
buttonz[buttonz.Count - 1].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radio_checked);
```

Below is my event handler:

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
}
```

The output is:

```
Button1 Radio checked! (1st button is checked)
Button1 Radio checked! (2nd button is checked)
Button2 Radio checked!
Button2 Radio checked! (3rd button is checked)
Button3 Radio checked!
```

So, the event handler is called when the button is unchecked either. How can I prevent this? I have read a few questions but they were complicated for my level therefore I couldn't extract the information I need. Explanatory answers are more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Winforms application. Forgot to add to the question.

Comment: You use same event handler for each button - of course same event handler is executed, when any button is clicked. Use sender argument to distinguish buttons or use different event handler methods.

Comment: I want to use the same handler, the problem was the handler being called twice. Thanks to people, they pointed out how can I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is that the event is called 
a) When the control is checked and
b) when the control is unchecked.
The hint for for this is that the event is called CheckedChanged.

In the event handler, you need to filter the calls. Cast sender to CheckBox and check the 'checked' property:

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if this is a radio button. It might be a checkbox!
    if(sender is RadioButton)
    {
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;
        if(btn.Checked)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the button is checked in the handler:

```
if(btn.Checked)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
}
```

Comment: Turns out there is nothing to explain:) +1 for the simplest answer, though I will accept the first answer. Thank you Lee.

Answer (score 0):

The event you've subscribed to is `CheckedChanged` so naturally it will be hit when you check and when you uncheck.

Change your function to look like this to only hit on the checked.

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;
    if(btn.Checked)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (btn.Checked)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just simply want write line for checked radio buttons add this if:

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;

    if (btn.Checked)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `CheckedChanged` event handler gets fired when a radio button is checked and when a radio button is getting unchecked, that's why it fires 2 times.

```
private void radio_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    {
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Radio checked!", btn.Text);
    }
}
```

like this the functionallity of the method is only run when the button got checked and not when it gets unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

The event you're subscribing to is called "CheckedChanged", so it means this event will be raised when checked state of the RadioButton is **changed** - which means it will be rised when it is checked or unchecked